# Is there a variant of std::lock_guard that unlocks at construction and locks at destruction in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, std

several times I wrote bits of code that would benefit from a "reverse" lock_guard, Like in this short example.

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(_eventQueueMutex);
while (!_eventQueue.empty())
{
    Event e = _eventQueue.top();

    _eventQueue.pop();
    _eventQueueMutex.unlock(); // Manual unlock
    dispatchEvent(e);
    _eventQueueMutex.lock(); // Manual lock
}
```

Is there a way to replace the inner unlock/lock by an automatic lock_guard in C++11 ?

Comment: If there isn't, it shouldn't be too hard to write yourself.

Comment: See https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1850  for boost implementation - but there seems to be some concern about nested lock_guard and unlock_guards.

Comment: Thanks, this thread helped a lot

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may write your own unlock_guard:

```
template <class T>
class unlock_guard {
public:
  unlock_guard(T& mutex) : mutex_(mutex) {
    mutex_.unlock();
  }

  ~unlock_guard() {
    mutex_.lock();
  }

  unlock_guard(const unlock_guard&) = delete;
  unlock_guard& operator=(const unlock_guard&) = delete;

private:
  T& mutex_;
};
```

Comment: Your are missing the `T&` member and possibly want to `delete` the copy constructor and assignment operator for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I just wondered if there was a more standard way of doing this in C++11, instead of writing something that already exists. Apparently boost has /boost/thread/reverse_lock.hpp that does the same thing, but not in C++11 for ownership reason I think